# Paste the content from dot . command in vim

Tags: vim, vim-registers

Given the word `foo` in a text, if I type `ciwbar<ESC>` while recording it as a macro in `w` register and then type in the command line
`:<C-r>w` it will brings me `:ciwbar^[`

However if i type `:<C-r>.` it will only brings me `bar`

But both commands, the `@w` and `dot`, are able to perform the **change inner word bar** in other parts of my text

Is there any way to get all the content from the dot as I got the `w` register? I would like to paste it and work to automate the last command in macros in some steps forward

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.` register and the `.` command are not the same thing. The `.` register stores the last text you have inserted and the `.` command repeats the last non-movement normal-mode command you executed.

Rather than try to force it to work another way, why not call a different registry and store values in there? The `.` registry will be overwritten by the last inserted text but many of the other registries are only changed when you actively tell vim to, so you can fill them yourself with the exact keypresses you want and call them again later.

Type

```
:reg
```

To see a list of what is currently inside each of your registries

Also have a look at this fantastic resource explaining vim's registers
https://www.brianstorti.com/vim-registers/

Comment: good to know, I wans't aware of this difference in `.` command and register; But before resolve this ask I will wait a little more to find out if there's a way to get the command inside dot as a string.

Comment: @intmarinoreturn0 Type `q.` and notice that vim will not start recording a macro in the dot register.

Comment: @intmarinoreturn0
In the link I sent, https://www.brianstorti.com/vim-registers/ you will see that the dot register falls under the 4 "read only registers". 

Rather forget about getting commands into the dot register and use one of the 52 other (a-z AND A-Z) registers to store the text you are holding. Use the dot register to hold the last piece of text inserted, the unnamed register ("") for the last text yanked or deleted, and 0-9 for the last 9 yanks.

Can I ask why you want to use the dot register?

Comment: Well, every day I open some config files and do some changes, the last changes are gotten by the dot command and I would like to write a script for when closing vim, be able to store a string for that command  (eg: ciwbar^[) automatically for further use. Using macro I have to explicitly start recording between a range of commands/actions and stop recording when I think it's done, but the dot command gets the last "atomic" changes automatically, I would like to persist it. A  thing that my intuition cannot tell while editing is whether or not it is a "atomic" change, only after finish it